# How to display the max value of a column with respect to only one other column?

Tags: postgresql

I have a dataset like so:

```
    story_name     | users  | age | reading_counts
-------------------+--------+-----+----------------
 Humpty Dumpty     | Elaine |   5 |             10
 Wheels on the Bus | Simon  |   3 |             15
 Dr.Seuss          | Simon  |   3 |             12
 asd               | Simon  |   3 |             10
 dsf               | Simon  |   3 |              6
 Dr.Seuss          | Elaine |   5 |              3
 asd               | Elaine |   5 |              7
(7 rows)
```

I want to be able to write a Query to display a the MAX reading counts with respect to each unique user. So something like this:

```
        story_name     | users  | reading_counts
-------------------+--------+----------------
 Humpty Dumpty     | Elaine |             10
 Wheels on the Bus | Simon  |             15
```

---

So far I have this query:

```
SELECT story_name, users, reading_counts
FROM story
WHERE reading_counts IN (SELECT MAX(reading_counts) FROM story GROUP BY users);
```

and I get this result:

```
        story_name     | users  | reading_counts
-------------------+--------+----------------
 Humpty Dumpty     | Elaine |             10
 Wheels on the Bus | Simon  |             15
 asd               | Simon  |             10
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function `rank()` in a subquery to assign a rank to each record within groups of records having the same user, order by descending reading count, and then filter on the top record in each group in the outer query:

```
select story_name, users, reading_counts
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        rank() over(partition by users order by reading_counts desc) rn 
    from mytable t
) x
where rn = 1
```

Note: if there top ties for a given user (ie several records that have the same, maximum reading count), they will all be returned.

Another solution, that could possibly offer better performance, is to use a correlated subquery to do the filtering, like so:

```
select story_name, users, reading_counts
from mytable t
where reading_counts = (
    select max(reading_counts) from mytable t1 where t1.users = t.users
)
```

This query would take advantage of an index on `users`.

Answer (score 0):

You couls use a subquery for max for each user  and join

```
  SELECT story_name, users, reading_counts
  FROM story
  INNER JOIN  (
    SELECT user, MAX(reading_counts) max_x_user 
    FROM story 
    GROUP BY users 
  ) t on t.user  = story.user and story.reading_counts = t.max_x_user
```